# How prove this inequality $\sum \left|\frac{z_{1}z_{2}}{(z_{3}-z_{1})(z_{3}-z_{2})}\right|\ge\frac{9}{4}$

Tags: inequality

let $z_{1},z_{2},z_{3}\in \mathbb{C}$,and such $$z_{1}+z_{2}+z_{3}=0$$

show that
$$\left|\dfrac{z_{1}z_{2}}{(z_{3}-z_{1})(z_{3}-z_{2})}\right|+\left|\dfrac{z_{2}z_{3}}{(z_{1}-z_{2})(z_{1}-z_{3})}\right|+\left|\dfrac{z_{3}z_{1}}{(z_{2}-z_{3})(z_{2}-z_{1})}\right|\ge\dfrac{9}{4}$$

My try: let $$z_{1}=a+bi,z_{2}=c+di,z_{3}=e+fi$$
then
$$z_{1}+z_{2}+z_{3}=0\Longrightarrow (a+c+e)+(b+d+f)i=0$$
so
$$a+c+e=0, b+d+f=0$$
then we have
$$\left|\dfrac{z_{1}z_{2}}{(z_{3}-z_{1})(z_{3}-z_{2})}\right|=\dfrac{\sqrt{(a^2+b^2)(c^2+d^2)}}{\sqrt{[(e-a)^2+(f-b)^2][(e-c)^2+(f-d)^2]}}$$

we only prove
$$\sum_{cyc}\dfrac{\sqrt{(a^2+b^2)(c^2+d^2)}}{\sqrt{[(e-a)^2+(f-b)^2][(e-c)^2+(f-d)^2]}}\ge\dfrac{9}{4}$$
then I can't.Thank you very much!

Comment: Is this true ? If $z_1=0$, then it is not satisfied.

Comment: @HeeKwonLee: I was going to say something very similar: $z_1=0, z_2=1, z_3=-1$ provides a counterexample. Also if two of the numbers are equal you will end up dividing by 0. Some restrictions on the numbers must be done.

Comment: It is probable that the inequality has some geometrical interpretation, i.e., $0$ is the centroid of a triangle?

Comment: If all my computations are right, if you take $z_1=a, z_2=b$, where $b>a>0$ are real numbers, the lhs equals $$1+2\frac{a(a+b)}{(b-a)(a+2b)}.$$ It looks like you can take many values that do not satisfy the inequality.

Comment: I think the identity we are looking for is,

 $\dfrac{(z-z_1)(z-z_2)}{(z_3-z_1)(z_3-z_2)}+\dfrac{(z-z_2)(z-z_3)}{(z_1-z_2)(z_1-z_3)}+\dfrac{(z-z_3)(z-z_1)}{(z_2-z_3)(z_2-z_1)}=1$ and in particular for $z=z_1+z_2+z_3=0$, we have $\dfrac{z_1z_2}{(z_3-z_1)(z_3-z_2)}+\dfrac{z_2z_3}{(z_1-z_2)(z_1-z_3)}+\dfrac{z_3z_1}{(z_2-z_3)(z_2-z_1)}=1$